# Proportional editing doesn't work correctly

Tags: edit-mode

When I use proportional editing on a certain area of selected vertices it affects the selected area AND some other random area that is outside of the circle and really shouldn't be affected at all.

[image: Before]
The selected area is the paw.

[image: After]
As you can see, the paw and other vertices in the vicinity get deformed, then there is a pause and no vertices move, then all of a sudden the front goes crazy.

Why does this happen and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Are there any modifiers on the object?

Comment: @MrZak yes, only the Armature modifier

Comment: Are there any shape keys? Armature modifier by itself probably isn't the reason

Comment: @MrZak yes, I am currently editing one of the shape keys (the first one actually)

Comment: Probably the mix of shape keys with armature is the reason. It also depends on what do you mean by first shape key (basis or key itself) however try to temporarily disable modifier and edit the mesh then. The fact that there is a pause before unexpected edit happens means this is caused by modifier